# Page returns 'Not Found' when opening URL to image in deployment but works in local machine. [Django Rest Framework]

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My Django REST API supposedly is able to GET and POST images. During development, I was able to save the image into the database and retrieve the saved image via the URL of the image. However, when deployed to Heroku, the page returns 'Not Found' when I clicked the URL to the image.

requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.2.10
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.0.8
django-heroku==0.3.1
djangorestframework==3.11.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
Pillow==7.2.0
psycopg2==2.8.5
pytz==2020.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
whitenoise==5.1.0
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('element.urls')),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py (Element App)

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Element(models.Model):
    element_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    element_tag = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    element_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    element_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='elements/')
    creator_tag = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    creator_link = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.element_name
```

serializers.py (Element App)

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from element import models

class ElementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    element_img = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Element
        fields = ('id', 'element_name', 'element_tag', 'element_type', 'element_img', 'creator_tag', 'creator_link')
```

views.py (Element App)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import filters

from element import serializers
from element import models

# Create your views here.

class ElementViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Element.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ElementSerializer

    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('element_name', 'element_tag', 'element_type',)
```

urls.py (Element App)

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from element import views

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('elements', views.ElementViewSet, basename='Elements')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

Note: The image along with its data is saved and can be seen in the admin panel. However, when opening the URL to the image, it returns 'Not Found'.

Both staticfiles and media folder are pushed into GitHub repository

When viewing in my local machine, if I open the URL to 127.0.0.1:8000/media/elements/picture.png, it returns the image. After being deployed, when I open the URL to project_name.herokuapp.com/media/elements/picture.png, it returns 'Not Found'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in serving your media files.

> Django is not built to serve static and media files in production [Deploying Static Files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/deployment/)

Since your using Heroku as your hosting platform, `whitenoise` is able to handle your static files. However, for media files a simple fix to the problem is to set up a free Amazon S3 account to host all your media files.

Here is a quick reference guide [Serving Django Media Files in Production](https://medium.com/swlh/serve-django-static-and-media-files-in-production-348fe6c7781d)